# DocumentDB Document Id

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using DocumentDB on azure and I don't want the auto-generated GUID that it gives me for an id on the top layer...example:

`{
  "data": {
    "Name": "Brian",
    "Last": "Coolest",
    "gender": "m"
  },
  "id": "7c572c3f-2ee1-43c9-bfb9-63b67542658d"
}`

how do i turn that id into:

```
 {
  "data": {
    "Name": "Brian",
    "Last": "Coolest",
    "gender": "m"
  },
  "id": "Brian"
}
```

on the creation of the document, is this possible? Thanks!

here is the method:

```
client.CreateDocumentAsync(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName), JsonSerializedDocument);
```

example of json structure:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "113118",
    "url": "/v1/rentalUnits/202020202",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you add your own field named "id" populate the field before you save the document, then DocDb will use the id you specified.  But, that means you have to control the uniqueness of the primary keys otherwise the next document that you save with `"id":"Brian"` will obviously overwrite the previous document.

Comment: o nice, im not exactly sure what you mean by populate the id field

Comment: cool cool, im assuming the id has to be on the top layer of the document?

Comment: You have to add a field to your object named "id" and populate it with the value you want before saving the document.

Comment: Yes, it has to be at the top level.

Comment: Do you have an example of the data prior to saving it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114868/discussion-between-cnaegle-and-adam-weitzman).

Comment: fixed my problem, maybe some code here will be useful - 
https://github.com/d1mnewz/CnapLvivBot/blob/master/CnapLvivBot.DocumentDbSeeding/DocumentDbDriver.cs
Create property called **id** in your entity
https://github.com/d1mnewz/CnapLvivBot/blob/master/CnapLvivBot.Data/Entities/Response.cs